# What could be the cause of Netlify React app long load time with empty gap of 10-11 seconds?

Tags: reactjs, performance, frontend, netlify

I have just recently launched a front-end React app on Netlify. The app, however, takes a very long time to load initially, ranging from 12-20 seconds.
[image]

Upon every load, there is a gap around 12-16 seconds, where nothing is accomplished. I have incorporated Lazy Loading in the routes to speed up the process. This cut the time in half, as it was 30-40 seconds before. I have reduced the bundle size as well, but the improvement was not noticeable. Any ideas as to why this is occurring?

Comment: There could be some script, most probably a 3rd party script that is stalling the render process.

Comment: @samuellawrentz That seems reasonable. Is there any easy way to find out which dependency is causing the delay? Thanks!

Comment: Check the networks tab on refresh, in your screenshot, the load time is around 16s. There could be some script/request that is still loading for 16s.